# How do I output multiple strings from multiple resources to another module using terraform

Tags: mongodb, azure, terraform

TLDR; bad question, syntax was right, other issue appeared, still trying to solve that part.

I've got 2 terraform modules;

one for creating app services, the module creates one app service, and is called multiple times in the root main file, using a for_each looping over a map of objects.

The second will create a mongodb-atlas instance. Also, I will be adding the IP's from the created webapps as trusted into the mongodb.
Every webapp can have multiple IP's, and there can be multiple webapps as well.

There's a dependency issue where the mongodb is starting it's deployment, but the webapp is not there yet, so the IP's aren't eighter. There I've got following solution for, I will output the IP's from the webapp module, and catch those values in the mongodb module.

Here's my issue, I'm not sure how I can output those values, as the output happens in every loop that is made.
I know how to output a single value, and use it in another module, my issue is the loop.

This is how I'm calling the webapp module:

```
module "app_service" {
  source   = "./modules/app_service"
  for_each = var.web_apps

 ....
}
```

This is how I will be adding the IP's to the mongodb:

```
resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "allowed_ips" {
  for_each = toset(concat(
    var.allowed_ips,
    flatten([for web_app in data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps : web_app.outbound_ip_address_list])
  ))
  project_id = mongodbatlas_project.project.id
  ip_address = each.value
}
```

This is that data block:

```
data "azurerm_linux_web_app" "web_apps" {
  for_each            = var.web_apps
  resource_group_name = "rg-${var.lztri}-web-${var.env}${var.stage != "" ? "-" : ""}${var.stage}-${var.loc}"
  name                = "app-${var.lztri}-${var.workload}-${each.key}-${var.env}-${var.loc}${var.stage != "" ? "-" : ""}${var.stage}-01"
}
```

As the data block is being executed immediately, before the webapps are deployed, this does not work. I can't put a depends on on the datablock, so I would like to give a set(list(string)) with all the IP's for all the webapps directly in the resourceblock.

So I'm looking for the output code, and how to integrate it into the resourceblock code.

I know the current resource block code works, if I first deploy the webapps, and in a later deployment the mongodb, but want to do it in one go.

Edit:
As mentioned, the 'depends_on' line where the mongodb module is called should stop it from being started. But, when I do this, I'm getting this error:

```
│ Error: Invalid for_each argument
│ 
│   on modules\mongodb\main.tf line 71, in resource "mongodbatlas_project_ip_access_list" "allowed_ips":
│   71:   for_each = toset(concat(
│   72:     var.allowed_ips,
│   73:     flatten([for web_app in data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps : web_app.outbound_ip_address_list])
│   74:   ))
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.azurerm_linux_web_app.web_apps is object with 1 attribute "api"
│     │ var.allowed_ips is list of string with 2 elements
│ 
│ The "for_each" set includes values derived from resource attributes that
│ cannot be determined until apply, and so Terraform cannot determine the
│ full set of keys that will identify the instances of this resource.
│ 
│ When working with unknown values in for_each, it's better to use a map
│ value where the keys are defined statically in your configuration and where
│ only the values contain apply-time results.
│ 
│ Alternatively, you could use the -target planning option to first apply
│ only the resources that the for_each value depends on, and then apply a
│ second time to fully converge.
```

It seems like the data block is started anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this (it will convert map to array)

```
locals {
app_insights_id = [
    for o in module.app_service : o.app_insights_id  ]
}
```

and then

```
module "mongodb" {
  source = "./modules/mongodb"

  app_insights_id                                  = local.app_insights_ids
  depends_on                                       = [module.app_service]
}
```

But it all depends what kind of type `app_insights_id` is in mongo module.

Comment: As I had so much trouble with this, I put it on any for now. 
But, as I'm reading my post again, I noticed I'm wrongly combining 2 of my approaches in one explenation. I'm going to edit my post to make it more clear.

Comment: You wrote `There's a dependency issue where the mongodb is starting it's deployment,`, but why mongodb cannot wait for web apps being created?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not really sure, I've got a "depends_on = [module.app_service]" in the general main file, where I'm calling the mongodb module, but it seems that is not enough...

Comment: Well, syntax is correct. And you are saying that mongo even with this `depends_on = [module.app_service]` starts before app services are created?

Comment: I don't think it tries deploying, but at least the data blocks seem to be ran. I'll add the error to the main post.